# Python interpreter with Linux Screen

Tags: python, linux, terminal

I was working with Python with a [Linux terminal screen](http://www.rackaid.com/resources/linux-tutorials/general-tutorials/using-screen/). When I typed:

```
help(somefunction)
```

It printed the appropriate output, but then my screen was stuck, and at the bottom of the terminal was "(end)".

How do I get unstuck? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can just feel RMS starting to bristle when you refer to a GNU project as "Linux Screen".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That program uses your pager, which is by default more.  You can exit just by pressing q.

Comment: Well that's a bizzare output of Python. Thank you! I really couldn't find the answer by googling.

Answer (score 10):

The standard on GNU (or other Unix-like) systems is to use the environment variable `PAGER` for the command that should receive output for **viewing one screenful ("page") at a time**.

Mine is set to:

```
$ echo $PAGER
less
```

Yours might be set to `more`, or a different command, or not set at all in which case a system-wide default command will be used.

It sounds like yours is modelled after the `more` program. The program is showing you page-by-page output, and in this case telling you you're at the end.

Most of them (basically, any pager more modern than `more`) allow you to go forward and backward in the output by using the cursor control keys (arrows and `PgUp`/`PgDown`), and many other operations besides.

Since you can do all these things wherever you are in the output, the program **needs an explicit command from you to know that you're done** navigating the output. In all likelihood that command is the keypress `q`.

For more information on how to drive your pager, e.g. `less`, read its manpage with the command `man less` (which, of course, will show pages of output using the pager program :-)